# C++ Why does the iterators behave differently when used with the find function?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Why does the following code snippet behave weirdly when it1 is constructed each time inside the while loop? In VS 2015, the loop does not terminate. Using gcc 4.9 it prints empty words after the first one. If I do not construct it1 inside the while loop, the loops works as expected? Does iterators do some kind of lazy evaluation?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
int main () { 

  std::string S("Hello world, the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over");

  std::vector<char> V(S.begin(), S.end());
  std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = V.cbegin();
  std::vector<char>::const_iterator it1 = std::find(it, V.cend(), ',');

  while (it1 != V.cend()) {
    std::cout <<"the string is: " << std::string(it, it1) << std::endl;
    it = ++it1;
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator it1 = std::find(it, V.cend(), ',');
    //it1 = std::find(it, V.cend(), ',');
  }  
}
```

Comment: You have two entirely separate variables that both happen to have the same name. That's a good way to confuse yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to advance the `iterator` to the correct position if you want find all tokens and your program doesn't cicle, for example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

int main () {
    std::string S("Hello world, the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over,,");

    std::vector<char> V(S.begin(), S.end());
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = V.cbegin();
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator it1 = std::find(it, V.cend(), ',');

    while (it != V.cend()) {
        std::cout << "The string is: " << std::string(it, it1) << std::endl;
        it = ++it1;
        it1 = std::find(it, V.cend(), ',');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am advancing the iterator to the correct position inside the loop. But I am creating a new iterator each time to hold the new index. As I am not using the destroyed variable it1 on both side of the expression I don't understand how the loop behave differently when I switch to the commented code.

Comment: But the `it1` in your while's comparison, takes the first declaration of `it1` and it´s only advance one by one.